$IDS Detector: There is a validation error with your HTML input. Your activity is a bit suspicious, hence aborting
Have started getting the below messages in logs.
Would this be because of someone playing with mailings Public View URL or there is a JS  code added by mailing creators/editors somewhere?
[info] $IDS Detector Details = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
[name] => x-javascript; charset
[value] => utf-8;base64,...
        [page] => /civicrm/mailing/data:application/x-javascript;


I recommend giving anyone who creates mailings the "Bypass IDS Check" permission. That will prevent them triggering this error. Really everyone on your staff should get that permission, since you already trust them to use the system.

thank you, I don't trust any of them at all though.
